# Postgres: Compare all fields from two tables and report back differences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that have the same fields. I want to compare each field of one table with the fields of the other table and report back any difference in the data.

I would like to do this in a dynamic way with out having to hard code the name of the fields in my query. Is this even possible or should I find a solution to this by using Python?

Example of tables:

```
     TABLE 1                    TABLE 2
FIELD1 : VALUE1            FIELD1 : VALUE1
FIELD2 : VALUE2            FIELD2 : VALUE2
FIELD3 : VALUE3            FIELD3 : VALUE3xxx
```

Query goes through all the fields and then says "A ha" Field3 do not match, I must show this to the end user"

Comment: Generally we ask that you *search for similar or identical answers before posting*. Google is also a good idea. In this case, a quick search locates http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pg-comparator/ ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [**Dinamic Sql**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html) and put it inside a function

[**Dynamic sql in postgres**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres)

For start you need contruct a sql to compare field name

And to get a table field names

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where
table_name='table 1';
```

Comment: Yeah, I need to read upon Dynamic SQL. I started approaching the solution to my little problem by using Python. If it gets too messy/dirty I will drop it though.

Thank you for your pointer by the way. Dynamic SQL is a good topic to know and I had forgotten it even existed.