# Postgresql: prepared statements in loop with date as parameter

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop

I have three prepared statements which create tables from different tables (multiple select statements + join + subqueries) to given date and then join two results of prepared statements namely:

```
CREATE TABLE _table1 AS
EXECUTE statement1('2000-01-01 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE _table2 AS
EXECUTE statement2('2000-01-01 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE _table3 AS
EXECUTE statement3('2000-01-01 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE _table_all AS
SELECT *
FROM _table1
LEFT JOIN
_table3
ON _table1.var1 = _table3.var1;
```

Statement3 is build on statement2 = select from _table2 (separate to make it more readable).

What I want to do is:

1. execute the same code for few dates -> pass date as parameter
2. save final table: _table_all as _table_2000-01-01, _table_2000-02-01 itd.

I do not know how to make such a loop / function which creates table and pass table_name and date as parameter.

Expected result:

```
FOR my_date IN ('2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', '2002-01-01 00:00:00'):

CREATE TABLE _table1 AS
EXECUTE statement1(@my_date);

CREATE TABLE _table2 AS
EXECUTE statement2(@my_date);

CREATE TABLE _table3 AS
EXECUTE statement3(@my_date);

CREATE TABLE _table_@my_date AS
SELECT *
FROM _table1
LEFT JOIN
_table3
ON _table1.var1 = _table3.var1;

DROP TABLE _table1;
DROP TABLE _table2;
DROP TABLE _table3;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different forms of `EXECUTE` in postgres

- The `EXECUTE` of the procedural PL/PgSQL language, described here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

- The `EXECUTE` of a prepared statement, as an independant SQL statement (not tied to a procedural language), described here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-execute.html

It's the **first one that fits your purpose** (dynamic SQL), not the second one. I suspect you were led to prepared statements by finding about `EXECUTE` and following the wrong trail. Prepared statements are not useful in your context.

See [dynamic sql query in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres) for a related Q/A, and in general you'll find examples of dynamic SQL on stackoverflow or elsewhere on the web. For instance, partitioning code tends to look like what you're after.