# Dynamically execute the create table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I'm trying to Execute below code

```
Execute '`create table employee(Empid Serial Primary key, Empname text, Dob Date)`'
```

I'm getting error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'create table employee(Empid Serial
>   Primary key, Empname text, Dob Date)'" LINE 1: Execute 'create table
>   employee(Empid Serial Primary key, Emp...
>                   ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'create table employee(Empid Serial
>   Primary key, Empname text, Dob Date)'" SQL state: 42601 Character: 9

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Which database are you actually using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic sql query in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres)

Comment: well error code is from postgres. and syntax is. better tell where you run `execute`?.. in function?.. as plain `SQL`?..

Comment: Actually im new to postgreSQL, In PgAdmin III have a option "Execute arbitary SQL queries", im trying to execute my code there. Im executing there as plain SQL, not in a function.

Comment: You don't need "execute" to run a plain SQL statement. Just run that `create table` (and get rid of those backticks)

Comment: yeah that is fine. But I have to create this table dynamically as i dont know how many columns could i add at the time of execution. it depends on the other variable.