# Postgresql: Set variable equal to a specific entry in an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table `newb` that looks something like this:

```
tablename | columnname
-----------------------
walls     |  id
floors    |  rowid
```

First I create an array:

```
CREATE TABLE finalsb
(
    tabnam newb ARRAY
);
```

Then I put data from a table into the array:

```
INSERT INTO finalsb VALUES(ARRAY(SELECT newb FROM newb));
```

The following statement displays `'id'` from table newb:

```
SELECT tabnam[1].columnname FROM finalsb;
```

I want to do something like:

```
Declare colvar varchar,tabvar varchar
colvar = Select tabnam[1].columnname from finalsb;
tabvar = Select tabnam[1].tablename from finalsb;
```

My main goal is to use:

```
SELECT * FROM tabvar WHERE colvar = "somevalue";
```

Can anyone tell me how I can declare the `SELECT` statement as a variable?

Comment: You cannot `SELECT ... FROM` a `VARCHAR` variable (`tabvar`). What is it that you are trying to do here? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want to assign a variable to whatever value holds inside the sleect tabname[....   command. @Nicarus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `select ... into variable` construct:

```
do $$
declare
    colvar varchar;
    tabvar varchar;
begin
    select tabnam[1].columnname into colvar from finalsb;
    select tabnam[1].tablename into tabvar from finalsb;
    raise notice 'tabvar: %, colvar: %', tabvar, colvar;
end
$$;
```

To run dynamic sql plpgsql's `execute` is needed:

```
execute format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = "somevalue"', quote_ident(tabvar), quote_ident(colvar));
```

for instance in form of functions' return statement:

```
return query execute format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = "somevalue"', quote_ident(tabvar), quote_ident(colvar));
```

Recommended reading:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

[dynamic sql query in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed!!

Comment: I am trying to execute command:                                                                Select * from tabvar where colvar = 2786683; Basically I want to use the form Select * from tablename where columnname = 2786683. The problem is I get error relation "tabvar" does not exist.

Comment: Did I solve your problem? Would you mind to accept answer if so?