# Execute Query string in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a query string in variable

suppose `Select Now()`;
I want to execute it same like SQL do.
I use

```
Execute 'Select Now()';
```

But It throws an exception

> prepared statement "SELECT now()" does not exist

and not allow me to execute it.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please show us your complete function

Comment: This is simplest one I tried. I will make function if it execute.

Comment: you can't use `execute` in SQL, this is a PL/pgSQL statement. You need a function (or a `do` block)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic sql query in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

You mess plpgsql `EXECUTE`:

```
t=# do $$ begin execute 'select now()'; end; $$;
DO
```

and SQL`EXECUTE`.

```
t=# prepare example as select now();
PREPARE
t=# execute example;
              now
-------------------------------
 2016-12-01 10:30:15.782433+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: I am using pgAdmin. How it execute in it?

Answer (score -1):

`'Select Now()'` Run like this in pgadmin