# Use dynamic parameter in SELECT query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is [another question with this title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres) - sorry to duplicate, but I simply cannot understand the answers to that question, so I assume plenty of others won't either and it will be useful to have a clear answer.

I am working in Postgres. I have a stored procedure called `duplicate_project` that takes a single parameter, the project ID.

I'd like to add a dynamic parameter in a WHERE clause in a SELECT query, to avoid having to hard-code a number.

So I'd like to avoid hardcoding:

```
SELECT duplicate_project(578);
```

And instead have something like this:

```
SELECT duplicate_project(SELECT project_id FROM folder WHERE name='foo' LIMIT 1);
```

Obviously this won't work, but is there a straightforward way to do something like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
select duplicate_project(f.project_id)
from folder f
where name = 'foo'
limit 1;
```

The `limit` is not really needed. In that case you get multiple rows that would show the result of `duplicate_project()` for each project_id returned.

Or:

```
SELECT duplicate_project( (SELECT project_id FROM folder WHERE name='foo' LIMIT 1) );
```

Comment: The query without a subquery and LIMIT would be the best case from my perspective

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus: but it does something different than the intended query from the question.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT duplicate_project( (SELECT project_id FROM folder WHERE name='foo' LIMIT 1) );
```

Another would be to use a `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT duplicate_project(x.project_id)
FROM (SELECT project_id FROM folder WHERE name = 'foo' LIMIT 1) x;
```