# Execute multiple SQL strings created in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to dynamically create audit tables for (almost) all tables in the database. I can generate the appropriate SQL dynamically, like so:

```
SELECT                          
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '
    || tab_name || '_audit(timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, entity JSONB NOT NULL);'
FROM (
    SELECT                                                                     
        quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name
    FROM                         
        information_schema.tables
    WHERE                                                       
        table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
        AND table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_toast%'
) tablist;
```

This gives me a series of rows of the form:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table1_audit(timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, entity JSONB NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table2_audit(timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, entity JSONB NOT NULL);
```

Etc.
What I am struggling with is actually executing those dynamically generated queries. From searching `EXECUTE` seemed to be the required function, but I could not get it to work without either producing a syntax error, or just doing nothing. I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [dynamic sql query in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12780275/1422451)?

Comment: Not really, wrapping in EXECUTE gives a syntax error

Comment: If you're using psql, leave off the ; at the end of the sql statement and run \gexec

Comment: That's the thing, I'm actually trying to write this into a django manual migration, so not via psql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a loop in a [`DO` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html):

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   FOR _sql IN
      SELECT format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I.%I(timestamp timestamptz NOT NULL, entity jsonb NOT NULL)'
                  , schemaname
                  , tablename || '_audit')
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables  -- only tables and partitioned tables, no toast tables
      WHERE  schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;
      -- EXECUTE _sql;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

I threw in a `RAISE NOTICE` to inspect the payload first.
Uncomment the `EXECUTE` line to actually execute.

You had `quote_ident(table_name)` *before* appending '_audit'. That would fail for all table names that actually require double-quoting. You'd have to do `quote_ident(table_name || 'audit')`. But I use `format()` instead. More convenient. See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

I also use [`pg_catalog.pg_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html) instead of `information_schema.tables`. Faster, and exactly what you need. See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

And I scrapped the subquery - not needed.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was after!