# Execute SQL returned as a select query result string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've got a function that I run using `SELECT functionName`. It returns me a single row with a single text cell containing another SQL query that I'd like to execute right away. Is there any way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why does the function return SQL code as text in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use PL/pgSQL to execute *dynamic SQL*

In case that the returned cursor of the queries has a *fixed* structure (i.e. same column names and data types) you may define a function retruning a `TABLE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exec_query(text)
RETURNS table ( id int)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY  EXECUTE $1 ; 
END 
$$;
```

The usage is as follows

```
select * from exec_query('select id from generate_series(1,3) t(id)')

id|
--+
 1|
 2|
 3|
```

In case the dynamic queries vary in the returned structure, define a function returning `SETOF RECORD`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exec_query(text)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY  EXECUTE $1 ; 
END 
$$;
```

But you will have to add the *column definition list* to the call

```
select * from exec_query('select id from generate_series(1,3) t(id)') as t(id int);
```

Otherwise a error is raised `ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12780275/4808122)